# Segmentation fault compile error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
long int n,i,j,k,q,sum,w,x;
long int a[100][100];
scanf("%ld",&n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    scanf("%ld",&x);
    for(j=1;j<=x;j++)
        for(k=1;k<=x;k++)
            scanf("%ld",&a[j][k]);
    printf("%ld ",a[1][k-1]);
    for(j=2*x;j>=1;j--){
        sum=0;
        for(q=1,w=j-q-x;q<=x&&w<=x;q++,w++){
            if(w<=0)
                continue;
            sum=sum+a[q][w];
        }
        if(w<=1)
             break;
        printf("%ld ",sum);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Given a 2D matrix of size NxN, print the sum of the elements of all its diagonals.

Input Format

First line of input contains T - number of test cases. First line of each test case contains N - size of the matrix. Each of the next N lines contains N integers - the elements of the matrix.

Constraints

```
1 <= T <= 100 
1 <= N <= 100 
-100 <= ar[i][j] <= 100
```

Output Format

For each test case, print the sum of the elements of all the diagonals, separated by newline. Refer samples for more clarity.

The compiler returns a segmentation fault error. How can I rectify it?

Comment: An array such as `long int a[100][100];` should be indexed from 0 to 99, not 1 to 100.

Comment: ...so given the constraints, you are probably indexing outside the bounds of the array, which should be `long int a[101][101];`

Comment: for ease of readability and understaning: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest 4 spaces for each indent level.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: what happens if the variable `n` receives a value > 100?  either the code needs to check that value to assure it is in the range 1...100 or (with a modern C compiler that allows VLA arrays) input the value `n` then declare the array as:  `long int a[n][n];`  Note, there are limits as to how big the stack can be.  (on windows, it defaults to 1 meg bytes)

Comment: Note: in c, array offsets start with 0 and end at the length of the (array-1).  So these kinds of `for()` statements: `for( j=1; j<=x; j++ )` would be better written as: `for( j=0; j<x; j++ )`

Comment: suggest using a debugger and watching the offset values for array `a[][]` to see where the offset is either <0 or greater than the array size

Comment: If your compiler crashes, you want to get a better compiler.  Your code successfully compiles on GCC 6.3.0; I wouldn't want to run the resulting program, though.